# Is it advisable to declare so many functions in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I feel like I'm declaring so many functions to use inside my main View.

So for example instead of coding:

```
Button(self.title) {
    // describing actions by hardcoding
}


Button(self.title) {
    // using aforedefined functions
    self.btnClicked()
    self.presentPopover = true
}
```

What is a good practice? What is more SwiftUI native? Should I consider some other ways?

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference is to keep `body` minimal, to achieve this you better to use functions.

Even further;

```swift
func buttonAction() { }

// If no extra action needed, you can pass reference to your function
Button("Title", action: action)

// If you use viewModel
Button("Title", action: viewModel.action)
```

Here is a bonus advice to keep body small as possible;

Transfer your `Text`, `Button` or any other `View` to `var` or `func` to see something similar below;

```swift
// MARK: - Image
private var image: some View {
   Image("")..
}

// MARK: Title
private var titleText: some View { .. }

// and so on..

var body: View {
   image
   titleText
   descriptionText
   actionButton
}
```